# Recursive function to find string length returning 6 too high?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to write a program to find the length of a char array using recursion, however my program is returning a value 6 more than the array length.

```
int n = 0;

int myStrlen(char string[]){

    if (string[n] == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        ++n;
        return 1 + myStrlen(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with getting rid of the global variable. And show your test main too.

Comment: ^^ Why? That won't affect the behavior of the program at all. While it isn't necessarily good coding style, it shouldn't affect the output as written.

Comment: @williamg But it does affect the behaviour... eg. if the function is called multiple times, which could be the problem here.

Comment: Btw., make your function parameter const (while not an real error without, again it's not only for good style: it makes passing literals possible without complaining)

Comment: @deviantfan That's a good point! I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 3):

The function can look the following way

```
size_t myStrlen( const char string[] )
{
    return *string ? 1 + myStrlen( string + 1 ) : 0;
}
```

As for your function then there is no need to use global variable `n` and the argument of each next recursive call of the function should be

```
myStrlen(string + 1)
```

Take into account that the function calcualtes the length of a string that is of a sequence of characters terminated with zero. If the character array does not contain a string then the behaviour is undefined.